# Send an electric signal with raspberry PI

Tags: raspberry-pi, wake-on-lan, signal

i would like to know if it's possible to Start my computer with my Rasp Zero, not with WAKEONLAN or things like that, just an electric signal as if i was pushing the power button. From a internet WebSite for example.
Thanks

Comment: This seems like it could be possible Hmm.

Comment: Have a look here it may be the same as a pi zero? or give you and idea i still need to pick up one of the pi zeros to play with. http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13989/use-raspberry-pi-to-control-pcs-power-switch

Comment: Yes still watching ;) thx for help

Comment: I remember powering on PCs by shorting two pins that's normally connected to power button. May be these can be connected to to pi and shorted programmatically (is it even possible to short them like this?)

Comment: I was thinking about this, plug my raspberry pi with 5V and 5V GND instead of the power button.